# WinRT MediaElement not working with InMemoryRandomAccessStream

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, mediaelement

We loaded video as bytes array, created InMemoryRandomAccessStream over this array and tried to MediaElement.SetSource. In UI we have message on MediaElement - Invalid Source. We tried to save this stream to file and read new stream from this file - works perfectly. Both stream are the identical (we check it using SequenceEqual).

What is the problem?

Part of our code:

```
var stream = await LoadStream();
mediaElement.SetSource(stream , @"video/mp4");

...

public async Task<IRandomAccessStream> LoadStream()
{
    ...
    var writeStream = part.ParentFile.AccessStream.AsStreamForWrite();
    foreach (var filePart in part.ParentFile.Parts)
    {
       writeStream.Write(filePart.Bytes, 0, filePart.Bytes.Length);
    }
    writeStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return part.ParentFile.AccessStream;
}
```

P.S - the mime-type is correct for sure

Thanks!

Comment: Post the code for the LoadStream function.

Comment: I paste code to post